# Typescript, can I exclude a specific label literal from a Record type?

Tags: typescript, typing

In Typescript, can I declare something along the lines of:

```
type SomeType =
  {
    [key: string]: string
    id: number
  }
```

or

```
type SomeType =
  & Record<string, string>
  & { id: number }
```

in other words, **I need an object with dynamic property names, plus a defined property name with a different type**. If I try the code above Typescript understands that all properties should be of type `Record<string, string>`, even if their identifier is `id`.

Comment: No, this is a missing feature with a longstanding open request at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867).  See the linked question and answers more info, alternative approaches, and workarounds.